# when i need to update the list i get this error ,Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, frontend

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

```
const CardList = ({nameList , deleteFunc}) => {
  // console.log(nameList);
  const Cards =nameList.map(({id,...otherProps})=>{
    return <Card key={id} id={id} {...otherProps}  deleteFunc={deleteFunc}/>;
  });
  
  return (
    <div>{Cards}</div>
  )
}

  export default CardList;
```

Comment: nameList is `undefined`, where is the part that you call to `CardList` component?

Comment: <div className={cardToggel? style.show : style.hide} >
    <CardList nameList={handelerName()}  deleteFunc={deleteHandeler} changeFunc={changeCards} />
    </div>
    
    </div>

Comment: const handelerName=()=>{
     if(filter.length !== 0){
         return state.filter((el)=> el.name.includes(filter) )
     }
     return state;
    }

Answer (score 0):

you can add default params in props. It will solve your problem.

```
const CardList = ({nameList = [] , deleteFunc = null}) => {...}
```